# Wordnet and Ontology software

Tags: computational-linguistics, software

Are there any software or tools for [Ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet#WordNet_as_an_ontology) and WordNet development?

Comment: Hello ARZ. Thanks for posting, but Ontology belongs to Philosophy not to Linguistics. Therefore your question _as is_ must be considered off topic. If it's not, please provide more context to show and explain what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for wrong hyperlink! it was updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I think it will be nice if your question text offer a brief description of Ontology and WordNet and what kind of development you are talking about.

Comment: I would say WordNet is on-topic and ontology is just one use for wordnet so I'm not sure it could go either way but it would be best to emphasize the WordNet connection and downplay the ontology part. Or just move the whole question to StackOverflow if "development" here refers to programming.

Comment: @Alenanno: there is a whole science of 'ontologies' which properly belongs to linguistics, namely lexical semantics. I say properly because it has been developed mostly in the CS/AI/text processing communities, and has little to do with the philosophical idea of 'ontology'.

Comment: @Mitch The link he used earlier lead to the Ontology I was referring to, and his question had so little wording that it made it not clear enough he was referring to something different.

Comment: This would be a good question for http://bit.ly/u4lZUG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many. A good place to start is: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/ .
It has many examples. Just to name several randomly:

- The Suggested Upper Merged *Ontology* (SUMO) is an *ontology* specified in first order logic. [SUMO mappings to WordNet 3.0](http://sigmakee.cvs.sourceforge.net/sigmakee/KBs/WordNetMappings/) are available. Email Adam Pease for more information.
- Paul Buitelaar, of DFKI-Language Technology in Germany, has developed [CoreLex](http://www.dfki.de/~paulb/corelex.html), an *ontology* and semantic database of 126 underspecified semantic types, covering around 40,000 nouns. CoreLex defines a large number of systematic polysemous classes, derived by a careful, semi-automatic analysis of sense distributions in WordNet.
- A [Resource Description Framework (RDF)](http://www.semanticweb.org/library/) representation of WordNet and *ontology* defining the terms used to represent the RDF version were developed by Sergey Melnik and Stefan Decker [email].